# How to get contents as array within the parenthesis using preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Input:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`attribute_id`,`user_id`,`history_id`), FULLTEXT KEY `value` (`value`)
```

Output:

$mathes[1] => primary key related options

```
$mathes[1] = array(attribute_id,user_id,history_id)
```

$mathes[2] => FULLTEXT KEY related options

```
$mathes[2] = array(value)
```

I want to get primary keys and fulltext keys using preg_match, Any possible suggestions are welcome.

Comment: So far what you have tried? Post your code, so we can help

Comment: Can you not query the database directly using `show index from <TABLE>`?

Comment: Fetched the query from dump file.